# Optaplanner - The Website resource does not exist

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm making a runnable jar for my project, and i keep getting this error when it starts generating the benchmark report:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The websiteResource (twitterbootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css) does not exist.
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.report.WebsiteResourceUtils.copyResource(WebsiteR esourceUtils.java:57)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.report.WebsiteResourceUtils.copyResourcesTo(WebsiteResourceUtils.java:33)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.report.BenchmarkReport.writeHtmlOverviewFile(BenchmarkReport.java:738)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.report.BenchmarkReport.writeReport(BenchmarkReport.java:287)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmarkingEnded(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:315)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.DefaultPlannerBenchmark.benchmark(DefaultPlannerBenchmark.java:109)
```

Everything else works fine since i added `"resources/"` infront of the drools and the benchmarkConfig paths.

Since there are a few more resources just for the benchmark, i probably would need to do the same for them also.

How can i get access to the resources for the benchmarks?

Comment: Which version is this? That should never happen if you're using optaplanner-benchmark.jar downloaded from optaplanner.org's zip or Maven Central. It's a bug, but I 've never seen it before. Are you building from source or anything?

Comment: I'm using the GitHub version, maybe that is the reason?

Comment: With "GitHub version" do you mean you've build from source with mvn? That should work too, I run the benchmarker from source in IntelliJ frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're building from source with an IDE (Eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans/...) and your project isn't set up correctly to also copy `*.css` files as classpath resources (so it has a specific exclude for css somewhere).

With a modern IntelliJ IDEA version, opening the `pom.xml` file, this definitely doesn't happen. With a modern Eclipse/NetBeans version, I'd presume the same.

Comment: Sorry about the delay for the reply on the comment. Yes i'm building with Eclipse IDE. I was guessing that i didn't set up my project correctly, as i doubted that this type of thing should happen.